# leaflet.js check if a marker has its bound popup open

Tags: javascript, android, leaflet

As per subject how can I check if a marker has a popup open?

eg.

```
var m = new L.marker([2,1]).addTo(map).bindPopup('test');
```

Clicking on the marker will obviously open the popup.

Is there any functionality such as:

```
if(m.popupOpen() == true) {
    // do somehting
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
m.on('click', function(e) {
    if(m._map.hasLayer(m._popup)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But it's very flaky. On chrome it will run, on android browser if will fire on the second click so it is not really reliable.

Is there any standard way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do a quick and dirty check on the _isOpen property of the _popup object contained within L.Marker:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView(L.latLng(0, 0), 0);
var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(0, 0)).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("Popup!");
var popup = marker.getPopup(); // returns marker._popup

console.log(popup._isOpen); // false

marker.openPopup();

console.log(popup._isOpen); // true

marker.closePopup();

console.log(popup._isOpen); // false
```

Edit: v1.0.0 L.Popup has an `isOpen` method:

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#popup-isopen

Comment: This'll work. But...I wish Leaflet would just expose all these useful "private" properties with accessors, so we didn't have to feel so quick and dirty...

Comment: just FYI for anyone wanting to check if a marker layer has a popup layer that's open for it....you can use layer._popup.isOpen()

Answer (score 0):

Now 2022 using leaflet V.1.7.1 the popup object doesn´t have the `_isOpen` property anymore.

You can now use the method:

`popup.isOpen()`

https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/reference.html#popup